# the error when I use R2WinBUGS packages

Tags: r, winbugs

all,
I employ the R packages R2WinBUGS to run Winbugs with R.However,the program
is not able to work well.The following codes attached

*panel.bug:*

```
model{
   for(i in 1:N){
       for(t in 1:T){
           y[i,t]~dnorm(mu[i,t],tau)
           mu[i,t]<-alpha+gamma1*a[i,t]+gamma2*b[i,t]+gamma3*c[i,t]+gamma4*d[i,t]+gamma5*e[i,t]+gamma6*f[i,t]
             }
     }

       gamma1~dnorm(1,25)
       gamma2~dnorm(1,25)
       gamma3~dnorm(1,25)
       gamma4~dnorm(1,25)
       gamma5~dnorm(1,25)
       gamma6~dnorm(1,25)
       alpha~dnorm(0,16) 
       tau~dgamma(1,1.75)
       sigma.tau<-1/sqrt(tau)
```

}

and the R codes

```
library(R2WinBUGS)
N=50
T=4
y=rnorm(50*4, mean = 0, sd = 1)
a=rnorm(50*4, mean = 0.1, sd = 1)
b=rnorm(50*4, mean = 0.2, sd = 1)
c=rnorm(50*4, mean = 0.3, sd = 1)
d=rnorm(50*4, mean = 0.4, sd = 1)
e=rnorm(50*4, mean = 0.5, sd = 1)
f=rnorm(50*4, mean = 0.6, sd = 1)

data=list("N","T","y","a","b","c","d","e","f")
inits = function() {list(alpha=0.99,gamma1=0.89,gamma2=0.2, gamma3=0.4, gamma4=0.1,     gamma5=1.1, gamma6=0.7,tau=0.1)}
parameter <- c("alpha","gamma1","gamma2","gamma3","gamma4","gamma5","gamma6","tau") 
msv.sim <- bugs(data,inits, parameter,model.file="c:/Bugs/msv/panel.bug",n.chains=2,
           n.thin=20,n.iter=1100,n.burnin=100,codaPkg=TRUE,debug=TRUE,DIC=TRUE,
           bugs.directory="C:/Program Files/WinBUGS14/",working.directory =  "c:/Bugs/msv/")
attach.bugs(msv.sim)
print(msv.sim,digits=4)
```

However,this codes have some errors as following

```
display(log)
check(c:/Bugs/msv//panel.bug.txt)
model is syntactically correct
data(c:/Bugs/msv/data.txt)
expected key word structure
compile(2)
inits(1,c:/Bugs/msv/inits1.txt)
command #Bugs:inits cannot be executed (is greyed out)
inits(2,c:/Bugs/msv/inits2.txt)
command #Bugs:inits cannot be executed (is greyed out)
gen.inits()
command #Bugs:gen.inits cannot be executed (is greyed out)
thin.updater(20)
update(5)
command #Bugs:update cannot be executed (is greyed out)
set(alpha)
command #Bugs:set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
set(gamma1)
command #Bugs:set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
set(gamma2)
command #Bugs:set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
set(gamma3)
command #Bugs:set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
set(gamma4)
command #Bugs:set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
set(gamma5)
command #Bugs:set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
set(gamma6)
command #Bugs:set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
set(tau)
command #Bugs:set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
set(deviance)
command #Bugs:set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
dic.set()
command #Bugs:dic.set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
update(50)
command #Bugs:update cannot be executed (is greyed out)
coda(*,c:/Bugs/msv/coda)
command #Bugs:coda cannot be executed (is greyed out)
stats(*)
command #Bugs:stats cannot be executed (is greyed out)
dic.stats()

DIC
history(*,c:/Bugs/msv/history.odc)
command #Bugs:history cannot be executed (is greyed out)
save(c:/Bugs/msv/log.odc)
save(c:/Bugs/msv/log.txt)
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks very much.

wanhai

Comment: What does "the program is not able to work well" mean? Does it give an error, is it taking a while to converge?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It would be very helpful if you could indicate what you are expecting to see, what you are seeing instead and what specific issue you are trying to tackle.  Then folks will have more to go on with which to offer some help. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi,mnel,thanks very much.The programs have some errors as following:
display(log) check(c:/Bugs/msv//panel.bug.txt)
model is syntactically correct
data(c:/Bugs/msv/data.txt)
expected key word structure
compile(2)
inits(1,c:/Bugs/msv/inits1.txt)
command #Bugs:inits cannot be executed (is greyed out)
inits(2,c:/Bugs/msv/inits2.txt)
command #Bugs:inits cannot be executed (is greyed out)
gen.inits()
command #Bugs:gen.inits cannot be executed (is greyed out)
.......

Comment: Hi, Ricardo Saporta.thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: EDIT your question to include the relevant error messages!!!

Comment: Hi,mnel,thanks very much.The post has been re-edit.

Comment: Well you don't supply any data, only a list containing characters. That's probably something that goes wrong here. Can't test it for you because I can't really be bothered with installing winBUGS now :) Edit: e.g., you need `data <- list(N=N, T=T, ... etcetera)`, btw assigning `T` a value probably isn't a good idea, might break other people's code who use it as `TRUE` (they shouldn't though).

Comment: Hi,Sacha Epskamp,thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is a list of character strings. Instead use:

```
 data<-list(N=N,T=T,y=y,a=a,b=b,c=c,d=d,e=e,f=f)
```

Comment: Hi,gjabel,thanks for your suggestions.I am learning from the website:http://plantecology.syr.edu/fridley/bio793/bayes.html.      The codes on this website could work well.