# Bayesian multilevel model with R2WINBUGS

Tags: bayesian, winbugs, r2winbugs

```
data <-
list("N","J","K","pa","unit","hosp","tech","teach","beds","unitsur","we","expe",
"full")

 inits1<-list(p0=0.1,tau1=0,tau2=0, beta =c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
inits2<-list(p0=0.5,tau1=1,tau2=1, beta =c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
data.inits<-list(inits1, inits2)

## Parameters to estimate
parameters <- c("beta", "tau1","tau2", "p0")

Burnout.sim=bugs(data, inits=data.inits, parameters, "Burnoutmodel.txt",
n.chains = 2, n.iter = 1000,    
bugs.directory="C:/Users/molasey/Desktop/WINBUGS/winbugs14/WinBUGS14/", 
debug=TRUE)
```

When I run the above code using the library(R2WINBUGS), the winbugs panel displays the following message:

expected collection operator c
compile(2)
inits(1,C:/Users/molasey/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmAA9bi/inits1.txt)
command #Bugs:inits cannot be executed (is greyed out)

Help me out pls.

Comment: This has been answered already, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081738/the-error-when-i-use-r2winbugs-packages

Comment: OK will check it out.